# Hello I am looking to know if anyone has developped something in kotlin or reactnativ to connect tezos wallet to android app? Thanks every body

Tags: tezos-client

We are a team of engineer end engineer student in charge of a project to dev a marketplace for french art school.

Comment: SE is for technical questions. Please use https://forum.tezosagora.org/ for more generic conversations.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Tezos Kotlin SDK](https://github.com/airgap-it/tezos-kotlin-sdk) project.